# How to show Category Name instead of Category ID in View from another table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Got a little problem with figuring it out, how can I achieve this...
There are 2 db tables - Category and Product.
[image]

In my Kategoria column I want to show exactly name of the category, not ID. Below my model classes.

Product.cs

```
public partial class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
}
```

Category.cs

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Promotion { get; set; }
    public string Image1 { get; set; }
    public string Image2 { get; set; }
    public string Image3 { get; set; }
    public string Image4 { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And the ViewPart:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryID)
```

When I type modelItem => item.Category.Name it doesn't work (column is empty). Any ideas how can i do this?

Controller:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private ProductContext db = new ProductContext();

        private void LoadCreateViewBagData()
        {
            string domain = Request.Url.Host;
            int clientid = (from a in db.Client where a.Domain == domain select a.ID).First();

            int maxID = db.Product.Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid).Max(c => (int?)c.ProductID) ?? 0;

            ViewBag.MaxID = maxID + 1;

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categories = db.Category.Where(d => d.ClientID == clientid).Select(b => new SelectListItem { Text = b.Name, Value = b.CategoryID.ToString() });

            ViewData["categories"] = categories;

            ViewBag.ClientID = clientid;
        }

        // GET: Admin/Products
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string domain = Request.Url.Host;
            int clientid = (from a in db.Client where a.Domain == domain select a.ID).First();

            LoadCreateViewBagData();

            return View(db.Product.ToList().OrderByDescending(a => a.ProductID).Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid));
        }
```

Comment: show me your controller code means how to capture data from data source ?

Comment: How are you populating the Model which is bound to your view?

Comment: If you are using EF then use Include(p =>p.Category) on your DbSet.

Comment: Added the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
```

Controller:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private ProductContext db = new ProductContext();

    private void LoadCreateViewBagData()
    {
        string domain = Request.Url.Host;
        int clientid = (from a in db.Client where a.Domain == domain select a.ID).First();

        int maxID = db.Product.Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid).Max(c => (int?)c.ProductID) ?? 0;

        ViewBag.MaxID = maxID + 1;

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categories = db.Category.Where(d => d.ClientID == clientid).Select(b => new SelectListItem { Text = b.Name, Value = b.CategoryID.ToString() });

        ViewData["categories"] = categories;

        ViewBag.ClientID = clientid;
    }

    // GET: Admin/Products
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string domain = Request.Url.Host;
        int clientid = (from a in db.Client where a.Domain == domain select a.ID).First();

        LoadCreateViewBagData();

        return View(db.Product.Include("Category").Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid).OrderByDescending(a => a.ProductID).ToList());
    }
```

**Tip for better performance**

You are using ToList before Where:

```
return View(db.Product.ToList().OrderByDescending(a => a.ProductID).Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid));
```

Use Where to filter and then use ToList to get data:

```
return View(db.Product.Include("Category").Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid).OrderByDescending(a => a.ProductID).ToList());
```

Comment: Getting this error: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'ProductModel.Product' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Category'.

Comment: Error occured on compile time or on run time? You are using EF Code First, right? All Migrations are executed? You have a relationship ("Foreign Key") on your database structure?
This code is right, de problem is with you sql server database structure.

Comment: It's on runtime, but I used a EF Database first. Maybe the problem is in relation in DB?

Comment: Check if Product table has a foreign key of Category table.
EF4? EF5? EF6?

Comment: The problem was with my DB and foreign keys. Fixed them and everything is working fine. Code listed above working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the line

```
return View(db.Product.Include(p =>p.Category).ToList().OrderByDescending(a => a.ProductID).Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid));
```

then below line will work in view

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
```

Change the product class as per blow

```
public partial class Category
 {
   public Category()
    {
      this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
public partial class Product
{
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public int ProductID { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public int CategoryID { get; set; }
 public decimal Price { get; set; }
 public int Promotion { get; set; }
 public string Image1 { get; set; }
 public string Image2 { get; set; }
 public string Image3 { get; set; }
 public string Image4 { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
 public int ClientID { get; set; } 

 public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Getting this error:
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'ProductModel.Product' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Category'.